# Can 'leave' mean 'forget'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

In a conversation like:

> **Person 1:** You can read a map, can’t you?
>
> **Person 2:** Yes, I can. But I left my glasses in England.

Does the verb "leave" mean that Person 2 forgot to bring his glasses, or that he left them **intentionally** because he thought he wouldn't be in need for them?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the context? There could be some wit to the response that might not be obvious. "left" can be both unintentional and intentional, also usually cleared out in the context.

Answer (score 17):

The word *left* can mean leaving something behind deliberately or unintentionally (i.e., through forgetfulness).

So, for a sentence like:

> I left my umbrella at home.

there is no way to tell if that was intentional or not. However, sometimes context will make it obvious which is case:

> I meant to bring my hat, but I left it on the countertop.

Clearly that is an unintentional act, whereas:

> I didn't think I'd need a map, so I left the atlas at home.

implies a deliberate decision as opposed to an act of forgetfulness.

M-W has two definitions which seem to account for both of these cases:

> #### [**leave**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leave) (*verb*)
>
> a : to cause or allow to be or remain in a specified condition
>   *leave the door open*
>
> b : to fail to include or take along
>   *left the notes at home*

Comment: The two M-W senses aren't intentional vs unintentional, but object-in-state vs object-in-place. Both a and b could be both intentional and unintentional.

Comment: Can anyone confirm whether in AmE you might also say "I *forgot* my glasses in England"? (where 'forgot' carries the meaning of 'left because I forgot about') I don't think you'd ever say this in BrE, but I seem to recall an American colleague of mine saying things like that.

Comment: @curiousdannii - "Cause or allow" sounds intentional to me, while "fail to include or take along" sounds accidental to me. I agree that _leave the door open_ and _left the notes at home_ could both be intentional or unintentional.

Comment: @Tim - I might say, "I left my glasses in England," or, "I forgot my glasses," but, "I forgot my glasses in England" sounds a bit off to my American ear, too.